# How do I remove this delivery notification from here?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I used STMP PHPMailer to send emails to newly clients on website. It works, but the weird thing is that it gives a delivery notification which I don't want.

How do I get rid of it?

[Image description of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Xa6.png)

Comment: Comment out line that prints that information. Without code - no help

Comment: Why is it "weird"? Computers always do things for a reason. Presumably you enabled the debugging mode or otherwise wrote code to make it output that. It's your code...check it to see what you did. If you can't find it and need help, then [edit] your question to show the code. It's unclear what you expect us to say to you otherwise? Please see [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue. It would also be beneificial to take the [tour], to get the best out of Stackoverflow. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enabled debug output, so all you need to do is not do that. You will have a line somewhere that says:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

or similar. Just delete it.